# How to retrieve location ID for our merchant

Tags: square, square-connect

We just integrated Square Point of Sales API to our iOS App. And we use our own Square account, say Account_A's client ID to setup SDK:

```
[SCCAPIRequest setClientID:<account_a_client_id>];
```

However when we need to perform a payment transaction with a SCCAPIRequest, it return with error immediately with error saying "Location ID mismatch.  The ID for the location selected in Square Point of Sale does not match the location_id parameter in the request.  Check the location_id parameter and the selected location and try again".

We realize that the Point of Sale App installed in merchant's device is login with their own Square account, say Account_B.

My question is, how can we retrieve the correct location_IDs of Account_B while our app is associated with Account_A?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're talking about multiple accounts, I'm going to assume you're using OAuth with your application. If that's correct, the best method for making this work would be to ask the merchant to choose the location they wish to use for the application. You would then use the corresponding `location_id` to pass to the `SCCAPIRequest`.

Comment: I had tried leave location_id as nil, it returns with error. It turns out the location_id is required after SDK version 3.3.1.

Comment: Good to know! I've removed that to prevent confusion from anyone else. Were you able to get it working by asking the merchant for their `location_id`?

Comment: We found that to retrieve the location_id, app must work with back-end server which using OAuth to require permissions from merchant's account first. I'll edit the question to show to whole process. Hope Square dev team add a clear flow chart in their docs :)

Comment: Yes, you must use OAuth in order to get access to other merchant's Square accounts. My suggestion was that once you've been granted permission, ask the merchant to choose which location they're going to use so that you have that information for future API calls.